# Removing lines containing symbol or empty line in bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

How to delete from all .asc files in the directory the lines containing '=' and 'HISTORY' (which is always capitalized) and all empty lines?

I think it will be something like:

```
for file in /media/linux/DATADISK/*.asc
do
    sed '/=/d' 
    sed '/HISTORY/d' 
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do all in one go.

```
sed -E '/=|HISTORY|^$/d' /media/linux/DATADISK/*.asc
```

Replace `^$` with `^[[:blank:]]*$` in addition to remove lines those containing only Tabs/Spaces too or use `^[[:blank:]]*\r?$` if your file's line-feed could be Windows-Style `\r\n`.

to update changes inplace, add `-i` option, see [`man sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120936/discussion-between-elena-greg-and-s).